# How to format C# code in an automated way?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editorconfig

I'd like to apply all formatting VS can apply to C# files (anything listed under `Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Code Style`, stored in a .editorconfig file on the project level), and verify whether it has been applied, but this should be initiated from the commandline and run on pretty much all files in a project, such that it can also run on CI builds for instance. I.e. maintain consistent code style across a large codebase, and enforced by CI so that lack of formatting leads to build warnings/errors; seems like a rather common requirement, there are tools for most common languages, but I couldn't find much specific to.Net ones?

I'm asking about VS, but if there's another tool which can apply similar formatting that would be fine as well; on that note: clang-format would be the ideal option were it not that it doesn't supply the same level of options VS has. Only option I see currently is creating something custom using [`EnvDTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.dte) to either manually go over all documents and call `Edit.FormatDocument` on them or perhaps to run 'Code Cleanup' on the solution. And then verifying whether everything has been formatted would entail applying the formatting and then checking if any files were changed.

Comment: Perhaps `dotnet format`? https://github.com/dotnet/format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dotnet-format` tool to format your source code. It will format based on the presence of a `.editorconfig` (or apply some defaults if there is none). You can find all the info for that tool [here](https://github.com/dotnet/format).

Comment: Interesting. Our code is targetted to .Net Framework, not Core, would that be an issue?

Comment: @stijn generally speaking no; C# is C# and this is just a command line tool.

Comment: I gave this a brief try in a sandbox and I have the impression it a) works ok based on the .editorconfig exported from VS, against .Net Framework 4.8 (needs that to be installed) b) does seem to support everything VS does. Not yet completely sure about b) because there's a lot to check but marking this as the answer already because it's close enough.